# console.log() to TextArea

Tags: javascript, qt, qml

I wrote a code that opens csv files with FileDialog and converts them to JSON. I sum the values ​​I want for each TimeStamp in the CSV file and print them to the console. In the function openFile() you can see the values ​​I send to the console. However, I cannot print the values ​​I have printed on the console to a TextArea or Label. I would be glad if you can help with this.

```
ApplicationWindow {
    visible: true
    width: 640
    height: 480
    title: qsTr("Demo App")


    function getControl(){
        return {

            data: null,
            getTotalBataryCount:()=>{
                let battery = 0;
                for(let i=0;i<this.data.length;i++){
                    battery += ((this.data[i]["battery0.mahConsumed"]!="--.--")?parseFloat(this.data[i]["battery0.mahConsumed"]):0);
                }
                return battery;
            },
            getAltitudeCountHigh:()=>{
                let amslHigh = 0;
                for(let i=0;i<this.data.length;i++){
                    if((this.data[i]["altitudeAMSL"]>amslHigh)){
                        amslHigh = this.data[i]["altitudeAMSL"];
                    }
                }
                return amslHigh;
            },

            getTotalFlighttime : ()=> {
                let flighttime= 0;
                for(let i=0; i<this.data.length;i++){
                flighttime += ((this.data[i]["flightTime"]!= "00:00:00")?parseFloat(this.data[i]["flightTime"]):0);

                }
                    return flighttime;


            },

        };
    }

    function openFile(fileUrl, items){
        return new Promise((resolve,reject)=>{
           var parser = [];
           if (fileUrl.toString())
               parser = csvJSON
           if (parser) {
               var request = new XMLHttpRequest()
               request.open('GET', fileUrl)
               request.onreadystatechange = function(event) {
                   if (request.readyState === XMLHttpRequest.DONE) {
                       let controlObject = getControl();
                       controlObject.data = parser(request.responseText);

                       items.push(controlObject.getTotalBataryCount(), controlObject.getAltitudeCountHigh(), controlObject.getTotalFlighttime())
                             console.log("deneme", items)
                            console.log(controlObject.getTotalBataryCount());
                            console.log(controlObject.getAltitudeCountHigh());
                            console.log(controlObject.getTotalFlighttime());
                       resolve(data);
                   }

               }
               request.send()

           }

           reject(false);
        });



    }







    function saveFile(fileUrl, text) {
        var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
        request.open("PUT", fileUrl, false);
        request.send(text);
        return request.status;
    }

    function csvJSON(csvText) {
        let lines = [];
        const linesArray = csvText.split('\n');

        linesArray.forEach((e, any) => {
            const row = e.replace(/[\s]+[,]+|[,]+[\s]+/g, ',').trim();
            lines.push(row);
        });

        lines.splice(lines.length - 1, 1);
        const result = [];
        const headers = lines[0].split(",");

        for (let i = 1; i < lines.length; i++) {

            const obj = {};
            const currentline = lines[i].split(",");

            for (let j = 0; j < headers.length; j++) {
            obj[headers[j]] = currentline[j];
            }
            result.push(obj);


        }


        return result;

      }


    FileDialog {
        id: openFileDialog
        nameFilters: [ "All files (*)"]
        onAccepted:  openFile(openFileDialog.fileUrl)

    }

    FileDialog {
        id: saveFileDialog
        selectExisting: false
        nameFilters: ["Text files (*.txt)", "All files (*)"]
        onAccepted: saveFile(saveFileDialog.fileUrl, textEdit.text)
    }

    menuBar: MenuBar {
        Menu {
            title: qsTr("File")
            MenuItem {
                text: qsTr("&Open")
                onTriggered: openFileDialog.open()
            }
            MenuItem {
                text: qsTr("&Save")
                onTriggered: saveFileDialog.open()
            }
            MenuItem {
                text: qsTr("Exit")
                onTriggered: Qt.quit();
            }
        }
    }



    ColumnLayout {
        visible:true
        spacing: 4

             Rectangle{
             id: flighttimerect
             width: 100
             height:100
             Layout.alignment: Qt.AlignCenter
             color: "grey"
                    TextArea{
                     id: flighttimerect1
                     textColor: "black"
                     text: "deneme"
                    }

             }

             Rectangle {
             id: batteryconsumptrect
             width:100
             height:100
             Layout.alignment: Qt.AlignHCenter
             color: "grey"

                    TextArea{
                    id:batteryconsumptvalue
                    text: "test"
                    }

             }

            Rectangle {
            id: flightdistance
            width:100
            height:100
            Layout.alignment: Qt.AlignCenter
            color: "grey"
                    TextArea{
                    id:distancetext
                    text:  ""
                    }

            }

            Rectangle {
            id: altituderect
            width:100
            height:100
            Layout.alignment: Qt.AlignCenter
            color: "grey"
                        TextArea{
                        id:altitudetext
                        text: ""
                        }

            }


    }


}
```

Comment: Does [qInstallMessageHandler](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtglobal.html#qInstallMessageHandler) help you? I can't remember if that works for console.log() statements.

Comment: Unfortunately that was not a solution.

Answer (score 3):

You can override the `console.log` method, or any other function, like this:

```js
(()=>{
  const console_log = window.console.log;
  window.console.log = function(...args){
    console_log(...args);
    var textarea = document.getElementById('my_console');
    if(!textarea) return;
    args.forEach(arg=>textarea.value += `${JSON.stringify(arg)}\n`);
  }
})();

console.log("Hello, world");
console.log([1, 2, 3]);
```

```html
<textarea id=my_console></textarea>
```

Comment: This will probably work with javascript on a website, but the question appears to be asking about javascript within Qt QML. Do you know if this answer will still work in that context?

Comment: I don't know what the syntax is for the QT api, but the same general pattern will work, yes. I just noticed that the code used XHR which is browser only didn't look too closely at all the code.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion but unfortunately the code you wrote will not work in QT.